# laravel unit test seeJson is fail with child level structure

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

I used phpunit to test the Laravel API. The API has return result like

```
{
    success: true,
    data: {
        'attr1': 'value1',
        'attr2': 'value2'
    }
}
```

when I used:

```
 seeJson([
    'success' => true
 ])
```

it's pass, but when I used

```
seeJson([
    'success' => true,
    'data' => [
        'attr1' => 'value1'
    ]
])
```

it's fail. any way to make it pass?

Please help me. thank you.

Comment: `attr1: 'value1'` should be  `'attr1' => 'value1'`

Comment: @cbaconnier  it's actually is 'attr1' in my test. I've updated my question

Comment: Please, notice `=>`. What's the error ?